# What does the `-svv` flag mean when running pytest via the command line interface?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, pytest, command-line-arguments

Can anyone explain what the `-svv` flag means/does when running pytest from command line? Such as:

```sh
pytest -svv
```

This is really driving me crazy, as I can't find it in [pytest's official documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/search.html?q=svv), its [code base](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/search?q=svv) or through a web search.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it either and I just run into 'OSError: pytest: reading from stdin while output is captured!  Consider using `-s`'. This error message is bad, I don't understand the global obsession with short cli flags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the same as passing

```
pytest -s -vv
```

where

`-s` disables capturing of stdout/stderr ([source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html))
`-vv` enables verbose output ([source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/output.html))

Specifically note that the increased verbosity specifier currently has no effect in base pytest above normal increased verbosity

> Using higher verbosity levels (`-vvv`, `-vvvv`, …) is supported, but has no effect in pytest itself at the moment, however some plugins might make use of higher verbosity

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot! I found the `-s` flag and `-v` flag on the man page and was wondering whether those are combined. However, did not think of the possibility that the verbosity can be increased.